# How to create custom rail along path?

Tags: bezier-curves, path

[image]

I have a rail and path. I want to set the profile along the path to make extrude on the path.

**I tried so far**

([image])

The top and bottom not match the profile. Having extra extrude or shape

[image]

Comment: It's the Solidify modifier that creates this, disable it?

Comment: Hello, atek.. it's not clear why you need a _Solidify_, here. Does declaring both curves as 2D, and checking End Caps on an 'Object' profile, go as far as you need?

Comment: @RobinBetts give thickness of 6inch

Comment: @moonboots to give thickness of 6inch

Comment: @atek can't you just set the X of your profile curve to that dimension?